# Trouble during Python Embedding on c++

Tags: python, c++

I want use python on c++.
So i jsut used test code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <python.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello world'\n)\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled with this command.

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -IC:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -LC:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs -lpython38
```

But it was not working and showing like this.

```
C:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyfMS5k.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
C:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyfMS5k.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
C:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyfMS5k.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
C:\Users\iotpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyfMS5k.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea for solve this trouble, plz help me.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using, and where did you get your python from? The lib may be incompatible with the compiler...

Comment: Im using gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0 version and i get python at https://www.python.org/

Comment: Why the C tag? You're using Python and C++

Comment: sorry it`s my mistake